# How to render Kendo UI grid from AJAX response data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this code that gets json object from a **static url** and then renders grid. But I want to use json data retrived as AJAX response and then render grid using this response text. **Because for practical deployment I can't use static URL.**

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {url: "http://url/returnsjsonobject.php"}
            //THIS GETS DATA FROM STATIC URL BUT I WANT TO READ DATA AS AJAX RESPONSE
            //like read: somefunctioncall
            //or like read: somevariable
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id: {type: "string", editable: false},
                    name: {type: "string"}

                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20
    },
    height: 430
    columns: [
        {field: "id", title: "ID", width: "20px", hidden: "true"},
        "name",
});
```

Thanks in advance for help and if you have any alternative method; I will be happy to try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that [`transport.read.url`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read.url) does not have to be a constant but might be a function:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: function(options) {
            return "somefunctionalcall?id=" + options.id,
        },
        dataType: "json"
}
```

or even define [`transport.read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read) as a function:

```
transport: {
    read: function (options) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "somefunctionalcall",
            success: function (d) {
                options.success(d);
            }
        });
    }
}
```